# cant convert value to int python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Code:

```
int(root.find('my_number').text) if root.find('my_number') is not None else None
```

Expected output should be type of number if this value is found, but if the value is not found it should be None. However, I am facing the following `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Shouldn't the statement only cast as an `int()` if my condition is met that `my_number` is existing?

Comment: `root.find("my_number")` exists but the `.text` property is `None`.

Comment: Maybe the number is in an attribute, not the text? Can you show your XML?

Comment: @Aplet123 yep! seems for that field I needed .text to check if it was None. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should check whats the return value for root.find() method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).